# Dicionário com listas como value

Tags: python

Eu tenho 2 listas como as seguintes:

```
lista1 = [
{'Idade': '8',  'Especie': 'Gato',      'Nome do Animal': 'Felix'},
{'Idade': '57', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Michelangelo'},
{'Idade': '12', 'Especie': 'Cao',       'Nome do Animal': 'Rantanplian'},
{'Idade': '2',  'Especie': 'Peixe',     'Nome do Animal': 'Nemo'},
{'Idade': '45', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Leonardo'},
{'Idade': '9',  'Especie': 'Cao',       'Nome do Animal': 'Milo'},
{'Idade': '57', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Raphael'},
{'Idade': '4',  'Especie': 'Peixe',     'Nome do Animal': 'Dory'} ]

lista2 = [
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Michelangelo'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Dory'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Ada', 'Nome do Animal': 'Rantanplan'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Leonardo'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Felix'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Raphael'},
{'Nome do Dono ': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Nemo'} ]
```

E pretendo obter um dicionario que faça para cada dono uma lista como value do dicionario a idade dos seus animais, tipo isto:

```
{ 'Eva': ['Felix', 'Nemo', 'Dory'],'Ana': ... }
```

Ja tentei fazer mas não me está a dar certo , só me esta a faltar um pequeno promonor que não sei qual é uma vez que o meu codigo apenas coloca um animal por dono :

```
myvalues = [a['Nome do Dono'] for a in lista2 if 'Nome do Dono' in a]


novo_dict = {}
for nome in myvalues:
    novo_dict[nome] = []
    for i in  range(len(lista2)):
        if nome == lista2 [i]['Nome do Dono']:
           novo_dict[nome] = lista2 [i]['Nome do Animal']
```

no entanto o que obtenho é isto:

```
{'Eva': ['Nemo'], 'Ana': ['Raphael'], 'Ada': ['Rantanplan']}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não ficou muito claro, mas eu acho que é isso que você quer:

```
from collections import defaultdict

resultado = defaultdict(list)

animais = [
    {'Idade': '8', 'Especie': 'Gato', 'Nome do Animal': 'Felix'},
    {'Idade': '57', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Michelangelo'},
    {'Idade': '12', 'Especie': 'Cao', 'Nome do Animal': 'Rantanplian'},
    {'Idade': '2', 'Especie': 'Peixe', 'Nome do Animal': 'Nemo'},
    {'Idade': '45', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Leonardo'},
    {'Idade': '9', 'Especie': 'Cao', 'Nome do Animal': 'Milo'},
    {'Idade': '57', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Raphael'},
    {'Idade': '4', 'Especie': 'Peixe', 'Nome do Animal': 'Dory'}]

donos = [
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Michelangelo'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Dory'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Rantanplian'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Leonardo'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Felix'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Raphael'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Nemo'}]

for dono in donos:
    for animal in animais:
        if dono['Nome do Animal'] == animal['Nome do Animal']:
            resultado[dono['Nome do Dono']].append(
                animal['Nome do Animal']
            )

# Modificando o  defaultdict para um dicionário normal:
resultado = dict(resultado)

print(resultado)

{'Eva': ['Dory', 'Felix', 'Nemo'], 'Ana': ['Michelangelo', 'Rantanplian', 'Leonardo', 'Raphael']}
```